# How to convert image to one dimension array using PIL?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to convert the image of a hand to an array were the hand pixels will be white and all the other pixels black.

The following is working code in GNU Octave which I am trying to replicate in python (see below for my code)

```
function image_out = processSkinImage(filename)
    Step 1...
    % Read the image
    original = imread(filename);
    ...
    Step 2...
    % Resize the image to 50x50
    image_resized = imresize(original, scale);
    [M N Z] = size(image_resized);

    % Initialize the output image
    image_out = zeros(height,width);
    image_out = zeros(M,N);
    ...
    Step 3...
    % Convert the image from RGB to YCbCr
    img_ycbcr = rgb2ycbcr(image_resized);
    Cb = img_ycbcr(:,:,2);
    Cr = img_ycbcr(:,:,3);
    ...
    Step 4...
    % Get the central color of the image
    % Expected the hand to be in the central of the image
    central_color = img_ycbcr(int32(M/2),int32(N/2),:);
    Cb_Color = central_color(:,:,2);
    Cr_Color = central_color(:,:,3);
    % Set the range
    Cb_Difference = 15;
    Cr_Difference = 10;
    ...
    Step 5...
    % Detect skin pixels
    [r,c,v] = find(Cb>=Cb_Color-Cr_Difference & Cb<=Cb_Color+Cb_Difference & Cr>=Cr_Color-Cr_Difference & Cr<=Cr_Color+Cr_Difference);
    ...
    Step 6...
    % Mark detected pixels
    for i=1:match_count
        image_out(r(i),c(i)) = 1;
    end
end
```

Here is what I wrote in python:

```
from PIL import Image as im

image = im.open('/Users/eitan/Desktop/eell.jpg')
image = image.resize((50,50), im.NEAREST)

grayScale = image.convert(mode='L')
grayScale.show()
width, height = grayScale.size

mid_pixel=grayScale.getpixel((width/2,height/2))
print (mid_pixel)

pixels = grayScale.load()

for i in range(grayScale.size[0]):    # for every col:
    for j in range(grayScale.size[1]):    # For every row
        if grayScale.getpixel((i,j)) < mid_pixel+15 and grayScale.getpixel((i,j)) > mid_pixel-15:
            pixels[i,j] = 255
        else:
            pixels[i, j] = 0

grayScale.show()
```

This results in part of the hand and part of the background both being white - while the rest of the hand is black.

Where did I get something wrong?

Comment: Apparently there are parts of the background that are the same level of gray as the hand. So the only thing wrong is your algorithm for recognizing the part of the image that is the hand. Using the actual color of each pixel might yield better results as long as no part of the background is that same color....

Comment: Where's the image please?